# Receive the latest UDP packet in C#

Tags: c#, udp, unity-game-engine, simulink

I'm using Unity to visualize a simulation where the data from the simulation is being sent to it via UDP packets from Simulink.  The problem I'm having stems from the rate at which Simulink sends out UDP packets and the rate at which my script in Unity tries to receive data from the UDP client.

For my Unity script, I create a thread that executes a simple function with a while loop and sleeps for the same amount of time it takes for the client to timeout (which is arbitrarily set by me):

```
public void Start() {
    //  Setup listener.
    this.mSenderAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    this.mSender = new IPEndPoint(this.mSenderAddress, 30001);

    //  Setup background UDP listener thread.
    this.mReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
    this.mReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
    this.mReceiveThread.Start();
}

//  Function to receive UDP data.
private void ReceiveData() {
    try {
        //  Setup UDP client.
        this.mClient = new UdpClient(30001);
        this.mClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 250;

        //  While thread is still alive.
        while(Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive) {
            try {
                //  Grab the data.
                byte[] data = this.mClient.Receive(ref this.mSender);

                //  Convert the data from bytes to doubles.
                double[] convertedData = new double[data.Length / 8];
                for(int ii = 0; ii < convertedData.Length; ii++)
                    convertedData[ii] = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 8 * ii);

                //  DO WHATEVER WITH THE DATA

                //  Sleep the thread.
                Thread.Sleep(this.mClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout);
            } catch(SocketException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here, if the timeout / sleep time is greater than the difference in time that Simulink sends out a UDP packet, my visualization will fall behind the simulation because it will read the *next* packet that was sent out and not the *last* packet that was sent out.  It is regarding the packets as a queue.

Is there anyway to just get data from the **last** packet received?  I know that there is at least one way around this, because if I use a `Rate Transfer Block` set to an equal or greater sample time as the UdpClient timeout it will work; but I'd like to make it more robust than that.

Since my packets contain full information about the state of my simulation (position, orientation, time, etc...) it doesn't matter if I never use data from intermediate packets; so long as I get the most up-to-date data, which would be from the last packet.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to timeout. Why not just receive all data that Simulink is sending until the sender timesout ?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the receive function.  Would it not only contain data from a single UDP packet?

Comment: The receive function fetches an entire stream of data, not just a single or few packets. But since the potential size of the entire receiving could be very large, each receive() call only fetches a limited amout of data defined by the buffer size. So you have to keep on calling the receive() function until the data remaining in buffer is zero.

Comment: And there is no need to sleep or timeout in between, as this will obviously create an overflow in the buffer for the duration of time your program slept. In that case the packets exceeding the buffer size will be just ignored or in other words, lost.

Comment: I just removed the sleep call and timeout to test it.  Seems to work just fine.  I think when I initially slept the thread I was thinking the Receive function didn't block and that it would cause my CPU usage to spike.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, since you are doing a blank continue; without checking exactly what type of exception has occurred in the socket, you will have to take extra care to abort this thread once your work is done. Otherwise, THAT might cause your CPU counters to spike!

Comment: Way ahead of you.  My OnApplicationQuit method already takes care of the Thread pretty carefully.  :)

Answer (score 0):

UDP is unreliable and the packets are not guaranteed to be received in the same order they are sent. My suggestion is to use TCP or put some sort of sequence number in your packets headers and keep reading the UDP packets and only select the newest packets.